# How to use one site.master in another project?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, .net-4.0, master-pages

I have a 2 projects, A and B in my solution. A is primary project and it includes B. I have created site.master in A and want to use this site.master in project B.
So that in project "B", I can use something like

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="B_page.aspx.vb" Inherits="B.B_page" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" Title="Project B Page"%>
```

where Site.Master is actually of project A.

I just want to use same site.master for another project.(Don't want to create duplicate.)

I tried adding Site.master of project A as a file link in project B but it gives an error(refer the png attached). [click here to see error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFhl2.png)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot reuse the same master files for 2 projects. You can do it only by adding the same master's `aspx, aspx.designer.vb, aspx.vb` files into the the project B and code it like

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="B_page.aspx.vb" Inherits="B.B_page" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" Title="Project B Page"%>
```